# Delete line from a text file?c++

Tags: c++

I will like to delete a line from a text file. First, I copy the content of the source file and mark  the deleted records as "deleted" to a temp file. Next, I overwrtie the source file from temp file excepted those mark as "deleted" record. My program will automically mark the name and next 3 line from the file as "deleted".

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string temp;
    string line;
    string strReplace_name;
    string deleted="deleted";

    int timer=0;

    fstream filein("filein.txt");
    fstream fileout("fileout.txt");
    if(!filein || !fileout)
    {
        cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout<<"Name: ";getline(cin,strReplace_name);

    string checking;
    int counter=1;

    while(getline(filein,checking))
    {
        if((counter%4==1)&&checking == strReplace_name)
        {
            goto sucess;
        }
        counter++;

    }
    cout<<"Error,No such name!"<<endl;
    goto error;


    sucess:
    filein.close();

    filein.open("filein.txt");

    while(getline(filein,temp))
    {
            if(temp == strReplace_name)
            {
                temp = deleted;
                fileout << (temp += "\n");

                getline(filein,temp);
                temp = deleted;
                fileout << (temp += "\n");

                getline(filein,temp);
                temp = deleted;
                fileout << (temp += "\n");

                getline(filein,temp);
                temp = deleted;
                fileout << (temp += "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                temp += "\n";
                fileout << temp;
            }
    }

    filein.close();
    fileout.close();
    filein.open("filein.txt");
    fileout.open("fileout.txt");
    if(!filein || !fileout)
    {
        cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while(getline(fileout,line))
    {
        if(line!=deleted)
        {
            filein << line << endl;
        }

    }
    error:
        return 0;
}
```

Here is my source txt file, and temp txt file(suppose I want to delete "nice").

Source file before running:

```
dumb
10001
16
girl
nice
10002
19
girl
ABC
1002
56
boy
```

temp file after running:

```
dumb
10001
16
girl
deleted
deleted
deleted
deleted
ABC
1002
56
boy
```

Source file after running:

```
dumb
10001
16
girl
ABC
1002
56
boy




1002
56
boy
```

Why my source code like this after running the compiler?Is there any problem with my code??

Comment: Why are you copying files twice? That's overkill. Why not create the new file without the deleted records in the first place, and then rename the temporary file back to the original file?

Comment: Unless you want to keep the original, there's no need for a backup at all. Hold the contents in memory and re-write the file sans the deleted records. This assumes that the file is always small enough to be held in memory, though. If that's not the case then Sam's suggestion is better.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the content but you have to remove it first.

The content of filein.txt is:

```
dumb\n10001\n16\ngirl\nnice\n10002\n19\ngirl\nABC\n1002\n56\nboy
```

You reset the cursor to the beginning of the file write:

```
dumb\n10001\n16\ngirl\nABC\n1002\n56\nboy\n
```

The result I get after running your code with your input data is

```
dumb\n10001\n16\ngirl\nABC\n1002\n56\nboy\nrl\nABC\n1002\n56\nboy
```

I can't reconstruct the empty lines in your output but a solution is to clear the file first or to write into a new file and move it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your final file is corrupt is your reliance on the default `mode` of the `fstrem::open()`. When you open `filein.open("filein.txt");` for the last time (it should really be called `fileout`, as you output to it), you should use:

```
filein.open("c:\\temp\\filein.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);
```

so the content of the file is erased first.

Then, also, what other people are saying.